# What are the implications of a shared git clone if the source repository is remote?

Tags: ssh, sync, git, clone, msysgit

So, the a git shared repository seems to be more or less perfect for keeping folders with large blobs in sync. I have something like 700 GB of pictures and videos I want to distribute across my computers, but using git without any other additions results in a huge disk usage overhead which isn't really needed.

Now, cloning with --shared (or -s) gives me a git repository without a local object storage (if I understood that correctly), which is pretty much what I need. However, the documentation starts with "When the repository to clone is on the local machine...". clone -s works just as well via SSH, but that leaves me wondering what happens if the repository to clone is *not* on the local machine. As the documentation of -s starts with that sentence, I feel like that whole case isn't covered. Is there anything I need to watch for except deleting commits on the remote side that might result in certain objects (that might still be in use locally) being garbage collected? (which won't happen anyway, as I want to use bare repositories on the server)

Answer (score 1):

I love git, but unfortunately, git is not right tool for this task.

Git was designed to very efficiently keep change history for mostly text content repositories.
While git does support keeping binaries, it will have to keep them forever in history so you can checkout to any revision, which is very expensive in terms of disk space.

Also, assuming that your binaries are not compressible (pictures, movies, music, etc), size of git object store will be about the same as tree checkout. In other words, for 700GB worth of original files, object store (`.git` directory) will consume about as much, and then more when you start committing - adding and removing content.

You can use so called shallow clone, which only keeps last revision of object in object store, but shallow repositories can be only cloned - not committed into. In this case, master git repository must be normal (not shallow) and will be still large, however all shallow clones will be reasonable size.

You probably will be better off by keeping simpler sync scheme like rsync. However, in that case you lose ability to review history - there is no free lunch :(

Comment: Sorry, but as I said, clone --shared does exactly that. Unlike a shallow copy, it doesn't even have a single revision worth of data in its object store. Try it... Create a git repository, put a picture in there and clone it via git clone --shared. The .git folder will be small, with the object store being practically empty. Usually, git assumes (in this state) that you can simply access the objects in the source repository (hence, I guess, the limitation to local operations in the git documentation). It's just that I can't find any information concerning shared clones with non-local origins.

Comment: Note that shared clone only makes sense if you perform clone on the same computer - read git documentation. For your situation to clone between computers, you have to use normal or shallow clones

Comment: But that's exactly what I'm asking for... A shared copy "makes sense" for me as well, because I don't want all those objects to clog up my hard drive. The git documentation explains how shared clones work locally - but git creates shared clones from a remote just as well. There are no warnings or anything when I clone a shared repository via ssh. So, I *did* read the documentation. I even quoted it in my original question. It's just not covering my case.

Comment: For git repository to work, git needs access to git object store, normally kept in .git directory. For local fs, shared clone can cheat and access another directory for object store. But for non-local fs, that is simply not supported by git - it really wants unobstructed local access to object store

Comment: That's simply not true. It is supported, as I stated before (at least in terms of "does it work"): Git clones remote repositories with the --shared option just fine. I'm not asking *if* it works, I'm just asking about the implications: What do I need to watch out for, what might be dangerous etc.

Comment: You think that `--shared` works, but it really doesn't. Note that `--shared` is simply ignored for non-local git clone - I just checked this on couple of my repositories, and there is literally *no* on-disk difference between `git clone ssh://server/repo` vs `git clone --shared ssh://server/repo`

Comment: I cloned my documents via ssh (with -s) at home overnight and saved quite some disk space. I cannot reproduce it here, which is kind of weird indeed - and as I'm at the office, I don't have that much time to check out why it doesn't work. Still, mounting a remote ssh folder, cloning (--shared) from that mounted folder and then re-setting the origin to the ssh address seems to work just fine. Again: What problems might arise from that? Checking out a commit that contains files that aren't present locally seems to work fine. That way I'd still have a shared clone with a remote origin...

Comment: How exactly do you "mount" ssh folder? Because mounted filesystem (samba/NFS) is considered local - you are fooling yourself. It DOES NOT work the way you expect

Comment: I mount an ssh folder via sshfs. Guess I'll just leave it like that. If the connection is interrupted git crashes, but apart from that I really don't see any drawbacks. How doesn't it work the way I expect it to?

Comment: You think that you are replicating git repository across multiple machines and are immune to any given box failure. However, you now really depend on one box that has real git object store and all other boxes are mounting that object store. This creates single point of failure - if that box fails, your git repository is gone. Top of the tree will be present on all other boxes, but history will be gone

Comment: No, I *think* that I have a nice way to keep my computers in sync. I'm aware of the critical status of the repository in the center... Of course I'd clone it to at least one other location and keep those repositories in sync. However, this way seems to be much more secure than e.g. unison or rsync to keep folders in sync, as all clients are aware of all snapshots and everything can be reversed if needed - and commits can be described. I *can't* keep the whole history of all my pictures on my laptops, the space just isn't there - but this seems to be the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this is not really answering your question, but... wouldn't [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/features.html) be far easier to keep two folders in sync?

Comment: Two folders, yes. But I have more computers around, with me usually jumping between desktop, laptop, tablet and work pc and my wife having her own laptop as well. Also, rsync doesn't give you the opportunity to add commit messages, which is nice because you know who did what and you can blame your children for deleting all those pictures from the last holiday... And restore them.